# Is there a way to explicitly parameterise for timezeone aware datetime object via typing hints in a function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime, typing

I want to deploy a type hint to show whether a datetime object parameter for a function should be timezone aware (or not).  Is there a way to do this of the form (or similar):

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

ref_datetime = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(dt.datetime(2023,1,20))

def func(num:int,ref_datetime:dt.datetime.tzaware) -> dt.datetime.tzaware:

    return ref_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=num)
```

As it stands, I have the following function, but it does not state whether the ref_datetime needs to be timezone aware or not:

```
def func(num:int,ref_datetime:dt.datetime) -> dt.datetime:

    return ref_datetime + dt.timedelta(days=num)
```

To be explicit, the following solutions are NOT what I am looking for:

A dosctring stating that the ref_datetime should be timezone aware; an extra required pytz.timezone parameter; an assertion in the function that the ref_datetime is timezone aware.

I want purely to be able to be explicit in the type hinting or something very close to that, granted the docstring solution is pretty close, but it is not sufficiently pythonic.

Thanks

Comment: In other words, you want an annotation that a specific attribute of an object does *not* have a specific value (`None`). I’m not sure that’s really possible. I’d go for some type aliases like `AwareDatetime` and `NaiveDatetime`, which would still be informal though. You can maybe create new types with these names instead, and require the caller to also explicitly annotate/cast to these types, then it would be enforced. Still no guarantee though that the caller is actually casting correctly, but it makes the programmer very aware at least.